# Repairing an RFID antenna?

Tags: antenna, rfid, repair, nfc

I have an RFID antenna that seems to be on a custom PCB. The issue I have is that the antenna on one side works fine, but the other side does not. I'm not sure if it is even possible or worthwhile to troubleshoot and try to repair the antenna. I would have first resorted to buying another one, but a vendor charges ~$350 for the unit since I guess it's niche... There isn't really a model number of the antenna and is used in a 3D printer to detect the material cartridge. Could a trace be cut somewhere or are there other obvious things to check/test?

[image: RFID Antenna]

Any help and advice is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From the picture, the antenna looks like a PCB trace antenna. This means that it is simply a long, usually coiled, copper track  with a suitable impedance and radiation pattern.

Unless this board has been excessively and repeatedly flexed, it is unlikely that a trace has been broken. Alternatively, the board could have been scratched or gouged which causes the break - look for evidence of this.

The more obvious culprit would be the wire connection. Cables are always weak spots and a break inside the insulation is common. You can de-solder the ribbon cable and try a new one. The image doesn't make clear what the connector is, but its probably an IDC connector.

If that doesn't solve it, then you could have a problem with the transmitter. You could rule this out by flipping the wire and seeing if the other antenna now works.

Lastly, you can replace the antenna PCB by redesigning the PCB and ordering new ones from a supplier such as OSHPark. You can try to copy the trace pattern by eye or use an [RFID trace antenna calculator](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/bc/ac/13/fe/69/fb/49/8a/CD00232630.pdf/files/CD00232630.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00232630.pdf) - check page 12 onwards.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. PCB should not been subjected to any flex or physical contact because it is mounted inside a metal chassis/frame. My knowledge on electrical side of things is limited, but I did a continuity test on the wires, from the solder point on the board, to the end of the ribbon cable, and they all seem to check out okay. Not sure of connector type, but is a 3 wire connector (2 gray 1 black wire), 3 wires are soldered onto PCB with connector on other end. I should try desoldering the 2 gray wires and flipping them? If problem is transmitter, can that be repaired? Thanks.

Comment: 1. The connector can be cut off and reused if you were to replace the wire - just leave enough wire left attached to solder to.
2. Yes, you can try flipping the grey wires.
3. Possibly with a picture of the transmitter and a circuit diagram. Typically, just look for any components that look burnt or have bad solder joints.

Comment: Thanks for your help MIL-SPEC, saved $350. Couldn't fix initially, but did more thorough examination. Used xacto knife to expose the antenna trace on the PCB board start -> terminal point. Continuity test failed. I examined the trace path deeper and found a mark/gouge at a spot along the path. I peeled back the layer on the PCB to expose the trace at this spot and put a drop of solder on it and covered it with kapton tape (not elegant and the solder barely sticks, but not sure of more proper way to do this). The continuity test now passes and the antenna works! Thanks again.

Comment: Fantastic! Glad to be of help :) I would appreciate if you could mark my answer as best answer, please.
Edit: To safely expose the track under the solder resist, you can use high-grit sandpaper.